# Rolling forward [hash-of-the-block]

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, reindex

can somebody explain me what's the meaning of a *Rolling forward* after a `reindex` of the chain in the log of bitcoind?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to the source of that phrase to your post?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad sure, and sorry for not doing it sooner